# Writing Wedge Product without Shuffles?

Tags: summation, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $\varepsilon$ and $\eta$ be multilinear, skewsymmetric forms taking their values on $\mathbb R$. How can I write the sum:

$$(\varepsilon\wedge \eta)(a_1, \ldots, a_{k}, a_{k+1}, \ldots, a_{k+l})=\sum_{\sigma\in Sh(k, l)} \textrm{sign}(\sigma) \varepsilon(a_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, a_{\sigma(k)})\eta(a_{\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, a_{\sigma(k+l)})$$ without using shuffles?

That is, I'm look to write something like $$\sum_{1\leq j_1<\ldots< j_k \leq k+l\atop 1\leq i_1<\ldots<i_l\leq k+2} (-1)^{j_1+\ldots+j_k}(-1)^{i_1+\ldots+i_l} \varepsilon(a_{j_1}, \ldots, a_{j_k})\eta(a_{i_1}, \ldots, a_{i_l}).$$ The above sum is not correct though, because there are overlapping indices.

The point is that once we know $1\leq j_1<\ldots<j_k\leq k+l$ the remaining indices $i_1<\ldots<i_l$ are uniquely determined, but I don't know to use this information properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a satisfying answer, but I give it a try.

Assume $\varepsilon$ and $\eta$ to be a $k$- and an $h$-form respectively. As you say, when you fix $a_{j_1},\dots,a_{j_k}$, with $j_1 < j_2 < \dots < j_k$, the remaining indices are uniquely determined and appear in the sequence of vectors in $\eta$ in increasing order due to the process of contraction. So there should be no sum over the $i$s, rather a remark that the $i$s are the indices which complete the sequence $j_1,\dots,j_k$ to $1,\dots,k+h$, and that they appear in increasing order.

Also,
$$
\begin{align}
(-1)^{j_1+\dots+j_k}(-1)^{i_1+\dots+i_h} & = (-1)^{1+\dots+(k+h)}\\
& = (-1)^{(k+h)(k+h+1)/2}.
\end{align}
$$
I did not check whether the signs are ok in general, but they look right in special cases where $h$ and $k$ are small.

Using contractions I end up with the expression you want to avoid, which is the only one I have always seen around in the general case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try to develop it further..

Comment: Do you need an expression like that for a particular reason?

Comment: As a matter of fact, it is for sake of clarity. Shuffles allow us to write the sum compactly, but for explicit computations it may be more obscure than using indices explicitly.

Comment: how about $$\varepsilon\wedge \eta(a_1, \ldots, a_{p+q})= \sum_{1\leq i_1<\ldots< i_{k_1}<\ldots< i_{k_q}< \ldots< i_{p+q}\leq p+q\atop k_1, \ldots, k_q\in \{1, \ldots, p+q\}} \varepsilon(a_{i_1}, \ldots, \widehat{a_{i_{k_1}}}, \ldots, \widehat{a_{i_{k_q}}}, \ldots, a_{i_{p+q}}) \eta( a_{i_{k_1}}, \ldots, a_{i_{k_q}}),$$ up to signs? Is the above sum clear to you?

Comment: I find it much harder to read than the one with permutations.

Comment: I agree that when you're familiar with sums indexed by shuffles it is much easier to read. Usually, what bothers me is computing the sign of the permutation, it is easy, but takes more time then compution $(-1)^{\square}$.